# How to print even and odd chars from a given string in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I was doing a problem in Python:
[Problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqktm.png)

However, my code is not getting the output I want. I want to store the strings in an array (2xtestcases) (given by the size of 'testcases' and then for each word loop over the index of the strings of the arrays and print the even and uneven word.

```
import numpy as np
import array as arr

# testcases
testcases = int(input())
# list of empty strings
strings = [None] * testcases

# list of translated strings
strings_translated = np.zeros((2, testcases))

for i in range(0, testcases):
    strings[i] = input()
    for k in strings[i]:
        if k % 2 == 0:
            strings_translated[1, i] = strings_translated[1, i] + k
        else:
            strings_translated[2, i] = strings_translated[2, i] + k

for i in range(0, testcases):
    print(strings_translated[1, i] + strings_translated[2, i])
```

I get the following error:

```
if k % 2 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: can you please provide inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: `k` is a string. You seem to be trying to use it as an int.

Comment: @khelwood. Or doing interpolation badly

Comment: `k` is not the index, but a single character: use `enumerate` to get also the index
`for k, _ in enumerate(strings[i])`

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the offending values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.
In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.  In this case, it would show your error immediately: `k` is a string so `k % 2` is an attempt to format the `2` with a string result.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with this site's purpose.  We need your question to be self-contained: the link to your problem assignment is useless in the long run.

Comment: You could do some basic debugging by using this visual tool - http://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you like to try this: (just a sample code to give you hints)

```
N = len(s)   # your string's len

evens = ''.join(s[i] for i in range(0, N,2))  # 'Hce' 

# then do the odds character as well
```

Comment: So I see that you are creating a even empty string that joins every even letter with join function. Is which library is the ```join``` function included in?
Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Hi, `join` is built-ins so you don't have to import any library. It works on string mostly.  Hope it helps, if you like the post, please upvote it?

Comment: Sure! Thanks for your help!